# Deriving an exact sequence involving the canonical divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For an algebraic variety $X$ and $D$ an effective divisor of $X$. One has the short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(-D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D \rightarrow 0 \tag*{(1)}$$
of invertible sheaves.
Now if $X$ is a surface with canonical divisor $K_X$ and $H$ a hyperplane section, I am given a long exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)) \rightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(K_X+H)) \rightarrow H^0(H,\mathcal{O}_H(K_H)) \rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)),$$
which I believe is obtained by taking sheaf cohomology of the short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(K_X) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(K_X+H) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_H(K_H) \rightarrow 0.$$
How is this short exact sequence obtained? I can't find a suitable invertible sheaf for the exact sequence $(1)$ to take tensor product with.

Comment: Take the first sequence with $D = H$, twist by $K_X + H$, and use the adjunction formula.

Comment: @Sasha I thought the adjunction formula is to compute an integer, i.e., $2g(H) - 2 = H \cdot (H+K_X)$? Upon twisting, my first term is done, but the middle term is $\mathcal{O}_X(K_X+H)$, and the last term is $\mathcal{O}_H(K_X +H)$. Is there another adjunction formula you're referring to?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_formula

Comment: @Sasha Sorry my middle term was wrong, I've edited it, it all make sense now, thank you.

Comment: Of course I realized that you second term was wrong, and in my comment I took this into account.